# Cannot import packages in sub modules

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm

I have a project structure like this:

```
project-root/
   source-root/
      sub-package/
         not_working.py
      working.py
```

If I import `BaseEstimator` in `working.py`:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
```

everything is .. working.

If I do the same in `not_working.py` I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/project-root/source-root/sub-package/not_working.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.base'; 'sklearn' is not a package
```

No idea what the problem is. I can load other modules

This is **working.py** and **not_working.py** - both have the same code.

```
import re

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
```

I can import numpy, pandas without troubles but it's not working for the sklearn packages.

---

I have set the interpreter to my local Python3.5 interpreter

[image]

and the packages seem to be installed correctly:

```
$ pip3 show sklearn
Name: sklearn
Version: 0.0
Summary: A set of python modules for machine learning and data mining
Home-page: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-learn/
Author: UNKNOWN
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: None
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requires: scikit-learn
```

Comment: Would you post the code from the two files (just so we can sanity check that) please?

Comment: @Splatmistro I updated my question - the two files only contain `import` statements and are identical.

Comment: Try adding an empty file `__init__.py`   in the `sub-package/` dir

Comment: @Splatmistro That is there. auto-generated by PyCharm

Comment: Hmm fascinating

Comment: @Splatmistro Yes indeed. I've opened another project and I am comparing the project configurations - they look completely the same to me - I've already tried invalidating the cache and restarting the whole thing but it's not working ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162436/discussion-between-splatmistro-and-displayname).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following our convo the `not_working.py` was called `sklearn.py`, hence the conflict of names meant that sklearn was merely a file not the package we want.

---

**Solution**
Rename `sklearn.py` to something else, e.g. `learner.py`

Comment: Thanks, would've never thought that that's the issue.